# ¿Qué es una "güisquería"?

Tags: definiciones, significado, españa

Según el Diccionario de la lengua, una [*güisquería*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JrvS87O) es simplemente:

> Establecimiento donde se sirve güisqui y otras bebidas alcohólicas.

Pero en [Word Reference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/whisker%C3%ADa) aparece como:

> Bar de alterne en el que las camareras suelen estar a disposición de los clientes para prostituirse.

¿Cuál de la dos definiciones es la correcta? ¿O pueden ser ambas?

Comment: Nunca lo he escuchado. Tal vez deberías indicar en que region/país  lo usan.

Answer (score 2):

Seguramente la mayor parte de estos negocios no están dedicados a este tipo de actividades (de ahí la definición de la RAE), pero de alguna manera se han ganado esa reputación.

Cerca de donde yo estudié el bachillerato, había una [whiskería](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c6blvgv) y por lo visto sí era un local dedicado a ese tipo de actividades. Sin embargo date cuenta de que el diccionario también incluye "[puticlub](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UjlzCLI)":

> 1. m. coloq. Bar de alterne donde se favorece o se ejerce la prostitución.

No imaginas a nadie nombrando o denominando a su negocio con el muy explícito "puticlub", ¿verdad? (por más claro que pueda dejar el mensaje sobre qué tipo de negocio es) Ni siquiera por el más eufemístico "[local de alterne](http://dle.rae.es/?id=26tSNXH)".

Entiendo que estos negocios siempre suelen ser un "bar de copas", una "whiskería" (o güisquería), una "sala de encuentros" o "club" (que sugiere un poco más esa "interacción social") o lo que sea, pero ninguno se anuncia claramente como "[prostíbulo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UQsTcwb)" abiertamente.

En teoría una whiskería debería ser un establecimiento dedicado a servir whisky, pero en algún momento este tipo de establecimientos se ganó esa reputación y güisquería/whiskería pasó a ser un eufemismo de puticlub/prostibulo/bar de alterne (porque suena muy bien y disimula mucho lo que ocurre dentro, y es lo suficientemente distinto al "bar" de toda la vida pero que deja bien claro qué son).

Este es uno de los casos en que la definición del DLE no es del todo completa.

Parece ser que ahora está sucediendo algo similar con los sitios de masajes o saunas o similar, que también ofrecen más servicios de los que cabría esperar. Si un local se llama "Spa" casi seguro que es solo un lugar para masajes, relajamiento, hidroterapia... Si se llaman "Sauna" o lo incluyen en el nombre, quizá no tengan solo baños de vapor (pese a que de acuerdo a la definición del DLE una [sauna](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XMCLLKw) no es tampoco un sitio para el alterne, como la definición de RAE para whiskería), pero esto también sería generalizar mucho.

Comment: En catalán tenemos algo parecido:: hablamos de una _casa de barrets_ (casa de sombreros) para denominar los burdeles. Viene de una tienda que, bajo la fachada de vender meros sombreros, disponía luego de un abanico de servicios más... extenso.

Answer (score 0):

Definitivamente, son las dos. La segunda definición es un eufemismo ampliamente aceptado.
La primera, sin embargo, esta cayendo en desuso desde hace tiempo, siendo sustituida por palabras menos específicas como bodega.